# Any plans for Spring 4.X to support JDO 3.1

Tags: spring, jdo

For a lot of upcoming Big Data solutions JDO looks like a better and unified standard approach.  The example being DataNucleous http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/index.html. Are there any plans for Spring to provide support for JDO 3.X...  Are there any challenges/issues with that?  Any update on this would be appreciated...

TY